# How to transfer button object as a function parameter?

Tags: javascript

I want to write the following code by using functions:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Test Java Script</title>
</head>
<body>      
        <button onclick=this.innerHTML=Date();> The Time Is: ? </button>
</body>

</html>
```

So I created a function and pass "this" as parameter, but it doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Test Java Script</title>
</head>
<body>      
    <button onclick=setTime(this)> The Time Is: ? </button>
</body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function setTime(Object b) {                
                b.innerHTML=Date();
            }
         </script>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: JavaScript does not use explicit types, so the `Object` part is extraneous. It's probably failing to compile there. (Keep your developer tools, F12, open to catch issues like that easily!)

Comment: Note also that you should define the function **above** your DOM element, or it will not be defined when the button tries to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Test Java Script</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function setTime(b) {                
                b.innerHTML=Date();
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>      
    <button onclick="setTime(this);"> The Time Is: ? </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Add quotes to onclick.
Remove "Object" from function declaration.
Click the button.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `Object` type from your function parameter and you're golden:

```
function setTime(b) {                
    b.innerHTML=Date();
}
```

As [Katana314](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576396/katana314) mentioned in their comment, JavaScript doesn't use explicit types.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3cyj5916/